# If we know the SHA-256 and SHA-384 hash of a string, can we find the actual string?

Tags: hash

SHA-256 of the word hello = 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824

SHA-384 of the word hello = 59e1748777448c69de6b800d7a33bbfb9ff1b463e44354c3553bcdb9c666fa90125a3c79f90397bdf5f6a13de828684f

Lets say the "hello" is unknown. If we know the SHA-256 and SHA-384 hash of the string, can we find the actual string that produces them?

Comment: In general, No. That's why they are hashes.

Comment: "hello" is short enough to be brute forced or to be stored in a rainbow table. Furthermore, it's likely to be in a dictionary, so a dictionary attack would work as well. In this case an internet search even shows results (including, in time, this one).

Comment: I used that word as an example. I am trying to find if there is some known relation between SHA-256 and SHA-384 that could lead to the original string (in case the string is less than 256 bits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cryptography Hash functions (e.g SHA-256, SHA-384) is ONE-WAY functions. That mean if we only have Y (Y = hash(X)), it is very difficult to compute X.

You can take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: I know that it is a one-way function. What I do not know is if there is some known relation between SHA-256 and SHA-384 that could lead to the original string (in case the string is less than 256 bits)

Comment: If a hash functions is designed bad, someone maybe recover original string from digest string. But in the case of SHA-256/384, I think that is very very difficult.

The output of a hash function has a fixed size, so you can find an string that have hash value equals to existed hash value by for through all values of output string.